# How to skip a node which raises an error when using cElementTree.iterparse()

Tags: python, xml, iterparse

I am trying to parse a very big XML file and do lower case and remove punctuation. 
The problem is that when I try to parse this file using the `cET parse function` for big files, at some point it comes across a bad formatted tag or character which raises `syntax error`:

```
SyntaxError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 639337, column 4
```

Note: It is nearly impossible for me to read the file, so I can not see where the problem is.

How can I skip or fix this?

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as cET

for event, elem in cET.iterparse(xmlFile, events=("start", "end")):
    ...do something...
```

Comment: I highly recommend the API of BeautifulSoup.

Comment: After iterparse hits an error, it will by definition stop. You can check the event stack it will always terminate at the error.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) instead of the standard library `ElementTree`; it supports the same API, but can handle broken XML; it'll attempt to repair it if at all possible:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
context = etree.iterparse(filename, parser)
```

Comment: Does lxml have some kind of iterateparse that can handle big files?

Comment: @user1262403: My code example shows you the `iterparse()` interface; `lxml` offers an extended ElementTree API.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like [`xmllint`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) to verify and clean your XML. The errors reported by this tool should help you to fix the XML file.

**Edit:** An example:

```
$ cat invalid.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
<bar>
</foo>
$ xmllint invalid.xml 
invalid.xml:4: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: bar line 3 and foo
</foo>
      ^
invalid.xml:5: parser error : Premature end of data in tag foo line 2

^
```

Comment: Thank you, but even if i see where the error is I still cannot fix anything in the file. It takes minutes even to open it, let alone navigate in it. Also I assume there are plenty of such errors. I think it has to do with the encoding when I open the file. Otherwise I would like to find a way to skip this part and iterate to the next